# How to hide Navbar in login page?

Tags: reactjs, navbar

I have been trying to solve this issue for a while now. I am trying to remove my Navbar from the login page. I have tried so many options but I don't really understand why is it not working. I also made sure my Login route is not falling under the Navbar components. I have attached the code below. Could anyone help me out?

PS: My Navbar is called as Sidebar in my code.

```
import './App.css';
import Sidebar from '../src/Components/Sidebar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import Overview from '../src/Components/pages/Overview';
import { Reports, ReportsOne, ReportsTwo, ReportsThree } from '../src/Components/pages/Reports';
import Team from '../src/Components/pages/Team';
import Maps from './Components/Maps';
import Login from './Components/Login';


function App() {


  return (

   <div className="App">

<Router>
      <Routes>
      <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>   
 
    <Router>   
      <Sidebar />
        <Routes> 
          <Route path='/overview' element={<Overview/>} />
          <Route path='/reports' element={<Reports/>} />
          <Route path='/reports/reports1' element={<ReportsOne/>} />
          <Route path='/reports/reports2' element={<ReportsTwo/>} />
          <Route path='/reports/reports3' element={<ReportsThree/>} />
          <Route path='/team' element={<Team/>} />
          <Route path='/maps' element={<Maps/>} />       
        </Routes>
    
    </Router>

   </div>  
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not very sure about your approach, the workaround that I would use is:
`{window.location.pathname !== '/login' && <Sidebar /> }`

The way I would approach this is by creating a PrivateRoute and PublicRoute components, use this https://medium.com/@thanhbinh.tran93/private-route-public-route-and-restricted-route-with-react-router-d50b27c15f5e

You should also use map to render these routes and add values such as `hideSidebar: true` to objects in which you want to hide the sidebar, then while rendering inside Route, check whether `!props.hideSidebar` like this:

```
const routes = [{path: '/login', component: LoginComponent, hideSidebar: true, requresAuth: false}]

// other part
<Router>
    {routes.map(routeItem =>
      routeItem.requiresAuth ? 
        <PrivateRoute {...routeItem} /> : <PublicRoute {...routeItem} />
     }
</Router>
```

inside PublicRoute.jsx

```
//code similar up to render in Route from the link
render={
 routeItem => 
   <>
     {!props.hideSidebar && <Sidebar />}
     <Component {...routeItem} {...props} />
   </>
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, but I don't think this has suited my approach.

Comment: The `{window.location.pathname !== '/login' && <Sidebar />}` part isn't working for you?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use 'Router' tag two times, and also you can use outlet for routs with Sidebar. So your code will be like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
  
  <div className="App">
    <Router>
        <Routes>
            <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>} />
            <Route
                element={
                    <>
                    <Sidebar />
                    <Outlet />
                    </>
                }
                >
                <Route path='/overview' element={<Overview/>} />
                <Route path='/reports' element={<Reports/>} />
                <Route path='/reports/reports1' element={<ReportsOne/>} />
                <Route path='/reports/reports2' element={<ReportsTwo/>} />
                <Route path='/reports/reports3' element={<ReportsThree/>} />
                <Route path='/team' element={<Team/>} />
                <Route path='/maps' element={<Maps/>} />       
            </Route>
        </Routes>
  </Router>
  </div>     
  );
}
```